# How can I store documents in firestore database without overwritting the data?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store "val credentials" inside "Credenciales" and  "val generales" within "Generales" for each user in the firestore. However, if I sign up as a new user, it overwrites the stored data of the old user.  Please, let me know how I can store both variables without replacing them.

Here's my snipped code:

```
val generales = hashMapOf(
    "Nombre" to nameEditText.text.toString(),
    "Celular" to celularEditText.text.toString(),
    "Cedula" to cedulaEditText.text.toString(),
    "Oficio" to oficioEditText.text.toString(),
    "Estado civil" to auto_complete_txt.text.toString(),
    "Calle" to calleEditText.text.toString(),
    "Sector" to sectorEditText.text.toString(),
    "Edificio" to edificioEditText.text.toString(),
    "Apto" to numeroEditText.text.toString(),
    "Ciudad" to ciudadEditText.text.toString(),
    "Residencial" to resEditText.text.toString(),
    "Telefono" to telEditText.text.toString(),
    )

    db.collection("Usuarios").document("Generales")
        .set(datos)

val credentials = hashMapOf(
    "email" to emailEditText.text.toString(),
    "password" to passwordEditText.text.toString(),
        )

     db.collection("Usuarios").document("Credenciales")
       .set(credentials)
```

Update:

```
val generales = hashMapOf(
        "Nombre" to nameEditText.text.toString(),
        "Celular" to celularEditText.text.toString(),
        "Cedula" to cedulaEditText.text.toString(),
        "Oficio" to oficioEditText.text.toString(),
        "Estado civil" to auto_complete_txt.text.toString(),
        "Calle" to calleEditText.text.toString(),
        "Sector" to sectorEditText.text.toString(),
        "Edificio" to edificioEditText.text.toString(),
        "Apto" to numeroEditText.text.toString(),
        "Ciudad" to ciudadEditText.text.toString(),
        "Residencial" to resEditText.text.toString(),
        "Telefono" to telEditText.text.toString(),
    )


    // Add a new document with a generated ID
    db.collection("Usuarios").document("Credenciales")
        **.add(generales)** // I get an unresolved reference error here.
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: Generales")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e)
        }
```

Comment: I suggest editing the question to explain what your final destination should look like.  Your code is behaving exactly as I would expect, but it's hard to tell what you want to happen differently.

Comment: The edit did not really help.  I can't tell what you want to happen that's different than what's happening now.

Comment: Dough, it works fine, but if sign up a new user it overwrites the existing data, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: You'll need some string to identify that user uniquely, then use that as the ID of the document.  You can't use the same document for each user as you are now.  add() will generate a new ID, but it seems you're not willing to use that.

Comment: lol, I do, but when I try it, it gives me an unresolved reference with the .add()

Comment: db.collection("Usuarios").document("Credenciales")
            .add(generales)
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: Generales")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e)
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `.document("Credenciales")` when adding and just have it as:

```
db.collection("Usuarios").add(generales) //etc.
```

of if you want to add to a sub collection it will be something like:

```
db.collection("Usuarios").doc(docref).collection(subcollectionRef).add(generales)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
        db.collection("Usuarios").document("Info")
            .collection("Credenciales").add(credentials)

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the update and vote.